# Rational valued functions on the Cantor set with $\int_{C} f^{3}d\mu=1 $

Tags: nt.number-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $C$ be the Cantor set as a compact Abelian topological group,  isomorphic to countable product of  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Its normalized Haar measure is  denoted by $\mu$.

> Is there  a positive continuous map $f:C \to \mathbb{Q}$  which is not  a  locally constant map but satisfy $\int_{C} f^{2}d\mu=1 $?
>
> Is there  a positive continuous map $f:C \to \mathbb{Q}$  which is not  a  locally constant map but satisfy $\int_{C} f^{3}d\mu=1 $?

In the other word does $\int_{C} f^{2}d\mu=1 $  or $\int_{C} f^{3}d\mu=1 $ imply that $f$ is  locally constant?

This  question can be considered as a generalization of the  equation $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}=1$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{3}=1$ on $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, let $S_n=\{x\in C\colon x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_{n-1}=0; x_n=1\}$.
Now inductively choose a sequence of rationals $q_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N q_n^2\mu(S_n)\in (1-2\cdot 3^{-N},1-3^{-N})$. You can check you have $q_n=\Theta(2^n/3^n)$, so that 1) $f$ takes countably many values; 2) $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, whence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The natural question follows: can we do a function which is locally constant around *no* point?

Comment: Clearly the exact same argument will produce a function that is locally constant around no point if instead of defining $f$ to be constant on the cylinder sets, one defines $f$ to be a locally constant multiple of $1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n 2^{-n}$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas  thank you for your answer. what is f  precisely?

Comment: So here is a concrete example. Take $f$ to be $2^{-n}$ on $S_n$ for $n>0$ and $f=4/3$ on $S_0$. With a little more imagination, you could build $f$ that is $2^{-n}$ on each $S_n$ with $n>1$ simultaneously satisfying your 2 conditions. My argument shows that there are *lots* of these functions - the construction is *very* flexible.